# Split one string into two using string.split java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I am trying to create two separate strings from one string around a delimiter using split. However it keeps telling me I am going out of bounds. The book I am reading uses this example:

reads: 3/4 or something

```
String currentFraction = fractionReader.nextLine();
String numHolder = currentFraction.split("/")[0];
String denHolder = currentFraction.split("/")[1];
```

When I try my own such as :

reading: 5.93

```
String moneyHolder = moneyReader.nextLine();
String dolHolder = moneyHolder.split(".")[0];
String centHolder = moneyHolder.split(".")[1];
```

I am guessing I have to make an array and then split it? All the examples I see online are for each loops printing stuff out. So how would I catch the left and right of the split into two strings?

Comment: Could you post a stack trace for the crash?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Money.add(Money.java:273)
 at Lab2Driver.moneyDriver(Lab2Driver.java:190)
 at Lab2Driver.main(Lab2Driver.java:30)






Sorry I am new to comp sci

Comment: It is, Sorry that did not show up at all in my searches. The book did not say what I had to escape or not I suppose, let me find and replace to double check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `split` method the pattern is regex. So dot means "any character" and split is done by any character. Try escaping this like this:

```
String moneyHolder = moneyReader.nextLine();
String dolHolder = moneyHolder.split("\\.")[0];
String centHolder = moneyHolder.split("\\.")[1];
```